# Apt pinning is pinning all sources

Tags: apt, ppa, pinning

I've installed a PPA, ondrej/php5, so I can install PHP 5.5 on a Ubuntu 12.04 server. However, I want to install Apache 2.2, and the above PPA provides Apache 2.4.

I created the file `/etc/apt/preferences.d/apache2`:

```
Package: *apache*
Pin: release o=LP-PPA-ondrej-php5
Pin-Priority: -100
```

Relevant lines from `apt-cache policy`:

```
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php5/ubuntu/ precise/main i386 Packages
     release v=12.04,o=LP-PPA-ondrej-php5,a=precise,n=precise,l=PPA for PHP5,c=main
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php5/ubuntu/ precise/main amd64 Packages
     release v=12.04,o=LP-PPA-ondrej-php5,a=precise,n=precise,l=PPA for PHP5,c=main
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
```

After creating the file, here is the result of `apt-cache policy apache2`:

```
apache2:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: (none)
  Package pin: 2.4.6-3+debphp.org~precise+1
  Version table:
     2.4.6-3+debphp.org~precise+1 -100
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php5/ubuntu/ precise/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.2.22-1ubuntu1.4 -100
        500 http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/main amd64 Packages
     2.2.22-1ubuntu1 -100
        500 http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main amd64 Packages
```

Why are official Ubuntu repos being given a priority of `-100`?

Comment: Apparently apt pinning is just broken: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=685215

Comment: how did you get your output?  I'm trying to find out how to obtain the release "o" and "n" value.

Answer (score 0):

Increase the priority of the package in the Ubuntu repositories:

1. Edit `/etc/apt/preferences.d/apache2`

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/apt/preferences.d/apache2
   ```
2. Add the following configuration

   ```
   Package: *apache2*
   Pin: release o=ubuntu
   Pin-Priority: 1000
   ```
3. Check

   ```
   % apt-cache policy apache2                
   apache2:
     Installed: 2.4.12-2ubuntu2
     Candidate: 2.4.12-2ubuntu2
     Package pin: 2.4.12-2ubuntu2
     Version table:
        2.4.16-4+deb.sury.org~wily+4 1000
           500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php5/ubuntu/ wily/main i386 Packages
    *** 2.4.12-2ubuntu2 1000
           500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily/main i386 Packages
           100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
   ```