# APT: additional repo for some packages

Tags: 14.04, apt, package-management, repository, official-repositories

we use an own repo for some packages. How can we avoid it, that these packages will be upgraded from other repo's (e.g if the packages in the official mirror are newer than our packages) by an apt-get upgrade ?

We use ubuntu systems (apt).

Comment: With apt pinning. Give me a ping, if the `hold` thing doesn't work for you. http://askubuntu.com/a/697110/367165

Comment: But even with this solution, the configurations of all the systems must be adapted. However, only one file needs to be created. Easy with `scp`.

Answer (score 1):

You can hold back a specific package so that it will never get upgraded automatically, neither through the official repositories, nor through your personal PPAs or whatever source.

The command is simple, just replace `PACKAGE_NAME` with the package name you want to hold back. You can also enter a space-separated list of packages:

```
sudo apt-mark hold PACKAGE_NAME
```

To undo this and enable automatic upgrades of this package again, use:

```
sudo apt-mark unhold PACKAGE_NAME
```

I believe that this only works for installed packages, when I try to hold back a not installed package, it does not save that state.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer.
I've found the following solution with pinning of apt and set priority's.

[Apt Pinning (ubuntuusers.de)](https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/apt-pinning)